# How to encode your data properly before inserting it into a SQL database

Tags: r, sql-server, dbplyr

Encoding problems are always painful. Here is what I am trying to do:

Example data `test.txt`:

```
Surname;Name
Şahin;Pakiz
Köpke;Marti
```

I read in the (UTF-8 encoded) file using

```
test <- fread(dec = ",", header = T, sep = ";", colClasses = "character", fill = T, encoding = "UTF-8", ...)
```

When I display the data I get the following

```
> test

   Surname  Name
1:   Sahin Pakiz
2:   Köpke Minna
```

and when I only want to get the `Surname` I receive

```
> test$Surname

[1] "Şahin" "Köpke"
```

which is correctly displayed so far.

Now I want to write the table into my SQL database using

```
dplyr::copy_to(con, df=test, name="TestTable",
        temporary = FALSE, types=rep("nvarchar(MAX)", ncol(dt)))
```

which in the database yields

[image]

I assumed that UTF-8 encoded strings should be fine for MS SQL Servers. I was wrong. I am not sure where I need to make changes. But let us assume that the data is always delivered in UTF-8 encoding.

Any idea where to start?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the current collation you are using.

```
SELECT Name, Description FROM fn_helpcollations() WHERE Name LIKE '%UTF8';
```

Or for the server :

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')
```

As Sql Server has been made by english people, it often lacks the UTF-8 or UTF-16 characters.
When creating you column, you should specify that you are using UTF-8 :

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable (
    Name NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8,
    Surname NVARCHAR(50) Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8
);
```

More informations [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/introducing-utf-8-support-for-sql-server/ba-p/734928)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. The UTF-8 collations are not available for our SQL Server (13.00.5102). Interestingly, a predecessor of mine was able to write data to a table and both characters are displayed properly in SQL Server Management Studio even though the table uses the native collation Latin1_General_CI_AS.
I tried `enc2native(Name)` but that leaves me with scrambled strings as well.